# Laravel - 404 error handling for different route groups

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

I want to show two types of 404 error screen for users, authenticated users with admin rights inside the route `/admin` see an error page style and unauthenticated guests in the route`/`see another error page, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Exception Handler](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#the-exception-handler)'s `render()` method. From the documentation,

> The `render` method is responsible for converting a given exception into
>   an HTTP response that should be sent back to the browser.

Instead of returning same views for all users, you can add the authorization logic in the `App\Exceptions\Handler` calss:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof CustomException) {
        if(isAdmin()) {
            return response()->view('admin.errors.custom', [], 500);
        }
        return response()->view('errors.custom', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```